# Sonar unable to connect to Jira through HTTPS

Tags: sonarqube, jira, sonar-jira

I have a Jira installation going (Jira 6.4.11), fronted by nginx w/ SSL.  I have turned on the remote RPC/SOAP service via the config file, and I can hit the url `/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2` on the Jira server and I get back a success page.  I also create a user for Sonar in Jira, and gave it User and Developer rights to all projects.

I have the URL in sonar set to the HTTPS address, ex. https://jira.mydomain.com, but when I get try to "Link to Jira" I get an immediate error saying:

> Impossible to connect to the JIRA server

I also not that I don't get any output in nginx access.log, nor any in the catalina.out or access.log for Jira.  If I change the URL to HTTP, ex. http://jira.mydomain.com, I still get an error, but I do get a 301 response log in the access.log of nginx.  It's as if Sonar is refusing to connect to SSL.  There are no error logs in the sonar.log at all.  In fact, there is not much in the way of log entries in that file to begin with.

I am stuck here.  I have no idea what to try, and with no log output, I can't tell what's not clicking to know where to even start looking.  Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Switching loglevel to DEBUG showed that this is a ssl connection error:

sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Solution should be to add the ssl certificate to the keystore of your jre (or the executing users keystore: /home/userxxx/.keystore)

Update:
I did not manage to make it work with the .keystore on our ssl environment.

Comment: I forgot about Java's ridiculously complicated keystore junk.  After fighting w/ the `keytool` tool and the config file a bit, I got to the next error.  Now I am getting "No service named jirasoapservice-v2 is available".  Is this the error you are seeing now as well?

Comment: For those that stumble here, to fix it I had to do the following:  1) Add the certificate chain to the JRE's cacerts keystore file.  2) Turn on the API setting in the JIRA admin.  It did not work trying to setup a "truststore" file in the sonar.properties at all.  3) Create an ID in Jira for Sonar to use that has rights to create and assign tickets.  I am now able to create JIRA tickets directly from Sonar.